# Htaccess alias redirect fake multilanguage url

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have a domain www.domain.com with this kind of url

**www.domain.com/my-italian-page.html** (already rewritten by others htaccess rules)

I'd like to create a fake multilanguage url like

**www.domain.com/my-english-page.html**

The user will see in the address bar the rewritter url **www.domain.com/my-english-page.html** but the content that I'd like to show is the original **www.domain.com/my-italian-page.html** .

I'm on a shared server so I can't use apache vhost rule so I have to find a solution via htaccess.

Someone could help me to find the right way?

Thanks

Comment: Do you want a static rewrite like always translate "la mia vacanza recente" (don't hit me I used google translate) into "my recent vacation" or do you want dynamic rewriting for multiple articles?

Comment: To be more precise: is an ecommerce. So I have to recreate a rewrite foreach product url.

Comment: Example I have in ITALIAN
www.mydomain.com/burro.html
My idea is to create a php script that will write into htaccess one single rule foreach product to get something like in fake ENGLISH
www.mydomain.com/butter.html
So if the user will visit www.mydomain.com/butter.html i'd like that url showed on address bar will be /butter.html but the content is from the original burro.html
Obviously i will save both clean url in a database then i will call the php script to write the rule into .htaccess.

Answer (score 1):

So you want english URLs pointing to italian content? Hope your php script that generates these rewrite rules does the translating. But you'd do this for each one of your pages:

```
RewriteRule ^/?english-page.html$ /italian-page.html [L]
```

for each one of your pages.

Comment: Yes, the php script translate everything except url. I think that some other rule is causing problem.

Comment: My htaccess `Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews -Indexes
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
 RewriteEngine On
 RewriteBase /acquista/      
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/acquista/(payment|admin|provider|partner)/
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !\.(gif|jpe?g|png|js|css|swf|php|ico)$
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
 RewriteRule ^/?butter-of-cacao-biologic.html$ /Burro-di-cacao-biologico.html
 RewriteRule ^(.*)$ dispatcher.php [L]
</IfModule>`

Comment: @user1625783 you probably want to put that rule *right after* `RewriteBase /acquista/`, or better yet, in the htaccess file in your document root, since it's `www.domain.com/my-english-page.html` and not `www.domain.com/acquista/my-english-page.html`

Answer (score 0):

Generally you want to keep the code executed in the web server as small as possible, so having a rewrite rule for each page is not usually a good idea. I suggest to implement this the way most CMS work when SEO URLs are enabled:

- Rewrite any url (`mydomain/anytext.html` [actually you should not use the .html extension either]) to a script (eg. `mydomain.tld/translate.php`)
- Use content of `$_SERVER['PATH_INFO']` (should contain `anytext.html`) to display the correct page
- Set correct HTTP response code if page does not exist: [`http_response_code(...)`](http://php.net/http_response_code) (see end of this answer for a function on php5 below 5.4: [PHP: How to send HTTP response code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3258634/php-how-to-send-http-response-code/12018482#12018482))

Sample .htaccess (actually originally "stolen" and severely modified from a typo3 setup)

```
RewriteEngine On

# Uncomment and modify line below if your script is not in web-root
#RewriteBase / 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-s
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
RewriteRule (.*) translate.php$1 [L]
```

Very basic pseudo-code-like (not tested, there may be syntax errors) example:

```
<?php
// using a database? you have to escape the string
$db = setup_db();
$page = db->escape_string(basename($_SERVER['PATH_INFO']));
$page = my_translate_query($page);

// no database? do something like this.
$trans = array( 'english' => 'italian', 'italian' => 'italian' );
$page = 'default-name-or-empty-string';
if(isset($_SERVER['PATH_INFO'])) {
   if(isset($trans[basename($_SERVER['PATH_INFO'])])) {
      $page = $trans[$trans[basename($_SERVER['PATH_INFO'])]];
   }
   else {
      http_response_code(404);
      exit();
   }
}

// need to redirect to another script? use this (causes reload in browser)
header("Location: otherscript.php/$page");
// you could also include it (no reload), try something like this
$_SERVER['PATH_INFO'] = '/'.$page;
// you *may* have to modify other variables like $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']
// to point to the other script
include('otherscript.php');
?>
```

I saw in your answer that you have another script - `dispatcher.php` - which you seem reluctant to modify. I modified my response accordingly, but please keep in mind that by far the easiest way would be to just modify the existing script to handle any English paths itself.