# why do I need to return http status

Tags: ios, ios6, httpresponse, passbook

I created a pass and web service. Now I can add this pass to device and also can register device to my server. I save data such as deviceID, passTypeIdentifier, pushToken, serialNo and authenticationToken, but I not yet return http status such as 201, 200, 401,... How do I response these http status to device ?

Comment: See this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3258634/php-how-to-send-http-response-code

Comment: Thanks ! I have search and test with header too, but when I test, I don't see that response !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before you send any content back to the device, add the following code:

If using PHP 5.4 or later:

```
$response_code = 201; // replace with required response code
http_response_code($response_code);
```

If using <= PHP 5.3:

```
$response_code = 201; // replace with required response code
header('X-PHP-Response-Code: ' . $response_code, true, $response_code);
```

In the console log, you should see the response code returned for each request that the device sends.

```
..... got response with code 201
```

Comment: can I do like this for other response : 401, 204 , .. ?

Comment: Yes - change the $response_code to be whatever you need it to be!