# jquery post .fail even when php succeed

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have a problem with my jQuery post request :

```
$.post(
  'http://localhost/***/ajax_bdd-change.php',
    {'id': _id, 'id_key': id_key, 'table': table, 'data': data})
    .fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
      alert('Erreur: '+jqXHR.responseText);
    })
    .done(function(data){
      alert($(data).text());
    });
```

And my PHP :

```
<?php
$id     = json_decode($_POST['id']);
$id_key = json_decode($_POST['id_key']);
$table  = json_decode($_POST['table']);
$data   = json_decode($_POST['data']);

foreach ($_POST as $k=>$v) {
  unset($_POST[$k]);
}
$rlt = array(
  'erreur' => false,
  'request' => 'none'
  ); 
$tmp = 0;
$request = 'UPDATE '.$table.' SET';

foreach ($data as $target => $value) {
  if ($tmp++>0)
    $request = $request.',';
  $request = $request.' '.$target.' = "'.$value.'"';
}
$request = $request.' WHERE '.$id_key.' LIKE "'.$id.'"';

$rlt['request'] = $request;

require('BDD_connexion.php');
if (!$rlt_bdd = mysqli_query($link, $request)){
  $rlt['erreur'] = 'Erreur: Update not done';
}
$link->close();

echo json_encode($rlt);
exit();

?>
```

Everytime I run my code, it follow the same path :

- PHP is correctly executed
- jQuery run `.fail()`

  - jqXHR.responseText is empty

I have try to force php to fail and at that time, the jQuery correctly run the done(function).

- PHP have some error
- jQuery run `.done()`

  - the alert show the php error

I have try many thing like force an UTF8 encode to each php string variable.
I even try to impose a simple string like `json_encode('hello world');`

After many test, it seem my previous informations :

> Maybe it is useful to explain that:
>
> - my javascript is inside a `laod()` php page.
>
> So it must have a structure like:
>
> - main.php --jQuery-->`load`(second.php into a `div`)
>
>   - second.php --jQuery-->`$.post`(ajax_bdd-change.php)
>   - ajax_bdd-change.php --return `$rlt` -->second.php(jQuery part)
>
> I do not mention it because I do not find it pertinent.

Is the cause of this problem. I have try a call of my php by post from a new html page without a `.load` and it is working perfectly.

Comment: You want to check `textStatus` in your fail callback

Comment: I try to check the error because I do not understand why I always run the `fail()`function. I just try the`textStatus` it contain `error`

Comment: I'd suggest not building a dynamic query directly with the $_POST variables unless you _explicitly_ define what values are allowed inside `id_key` and `table`, as well as actually using `mysqli` for what makes it valuable - data binding / prepared statements for SQL Injection prevention. That script is incredibly dangerous as-is. See here for binding: http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php

Comment: It seem your suggestion can have an influence...I find that everything work correctly but when I add `mysqli_query($link, $request)` it start to not bug.

Comment: "Nate I" my `$_POST`are explecitly define and most of them are not given by the user but are data transmit directly by the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have find a resolution.
In fact, my code is more complex, and the jQuery `.post` is done in a `.submit` of a `<form>` inside the script part of an jQuery DialogBox.
So the form was finished to submit before the php response when this on have a Database Query.

*In resolution I change this submit with just a* `.click`*, and I manualy close when I recive a response from the server.*

Answer (score 1):

The response code, if nothing bad occurred on the server, should be `200`.

It's highly likely, based off the observations you've made, that the response code is something other than `200`. Also note, jQuery, or any other framework, doesn't know whether custom code, written on the server, was executed coherently. Usually, the only indication to the client is the `response code`.

jQuery [source](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/0bd98b1b13872255225358f328bee1f980755483/src/ajax.js#L735)

Comment: Actually my status response code is `0` so it mean I do not have a response ? How can this be possible if the php is correctly executed ? (maybe it is not, but my database is correclty updated...and if I do another code after this one too is executed...)

Comment: updated my answer with the source in jquery where the condition, based off the `responsecode`, is made.

Comment: sounds like, in PHP, you have to set the response header directly; in the fashion described in this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3258634/php-how-to-send-http-response-code

Comment: I just try `http_response_code(200);` just before the `die(json_encode(...));` But that have no influance. It must be add in an other way ?

Comment: check your configuration files, must be something external to the code you're actively working with...

Comment: it seem that is the `mysqli_query` that is generate this issue. Is it possible ? Can I try a substitue or manually remove this generation ?

Answer (score 0):

First you have to decide that you want JSON  in you AJAX Query like so:

```
    $.ajax({
        url:        'http://localhost/***/ajax_bdd-change.php',
        dataType:   'json',     //EXPLICITLY SET THIS TO JSON
        cache:      false,
        type:       "POST",
        data:       {
            id          : _id,
            id_key      : id_key,
            table       : table,
            data        : data
        },

        success: function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
            if(data){
                alert("DATA CAME BACK AS JSON...");
                console.log(data);
                // YOU REALLY DON'T WANT TO DO THIS: $(data).text() 
                // THE .text() METHOD IS FOR THE DOM AND YOU ARE IN READING MODE TOO
                // data SHOULD CONTAIN THESE: request AND erreur
                // SO YOU CAN EITHER CHECK THE SQL OR THE ERROR LIKE SO:
                // I WOULD PREFER USING console.log(data.request)
                alert(data.request);
                alert(data.erreur);
            }
        },

        error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            alert('Erreur: '+jqXHR.responseText);
        },

        complete: function (jqXHR, textStatus) {
            //DO SOMETHING HERE IF YOU WISH TO
        } 
    });
```

And this is your PHP Code:

```
    <?php
        $id     = isset($_POST['id'])       ? htmlspecialchars(trim($_POST['id']))      : null;
        $id_key = isset($_POST['id_key'])   ? htmlspecialchars(trim($_POST['id_key']))  : null;
        $table  = isset($_POST['table'])    ? htmlspecialchars(trim($_POST['table']))   : null;
        $data   = isset($_POST['data'])     ? htmlspecialchars(trim($_POST['data']))    : null;


        foreach ($_POST as $k=>$v) {
            unset($_POST[$k]);
        }

        $rlt    = array(
            'erreur'    => false,
            'request'   => 'none'
        );

        $updateSQL  = 'UPDATE '. $table . ' SET ';
        if($data){
            foreach ($data as $target => $value) {
                $updateSQL .= ' ' . $target . ' = "' . $value . '", ';
            }
            $updateSQL  = rtrim($updateSQL, ", ");
            // LIKE CLAUSE IS NOT SO FUNKY HERE: DO YOU WANT TO DO "EQUALS"?
            // ' WHERE ' . $id_key . ' = "' . $id. '"';
            $condition  = ' WHERE ' . $id_key . ' LIKE "' . $id. '"';
            $request    = $updateSQL . $condition;

            $rlt['request'] = $request; 
            require('BDD_connexion.php');
            if (!$rlt_bdd = mysqli_query($link, $request)){
                $rlt['erreur'] = 'Erreur: Update not done';
            }
            $link->close();
        }

        die( json_encode($rlt) );
```

Hope this is a little close...

Comment: I try your correction, but the same thing append:  - PHP correctly executed  - jQuery run `error()` and the `responseText` is empty

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

// Javascript

```
var params = {
    id: _id,
    id_key: id_key,
    table: table,
    data: data
};

// explicitely tells javascript you're expecting json response
// with this $.post shortcut

$.post('url', params, function(data) {
    //console.log(data)
    if (data.erreur) {
        // Error occured
    } else {
        // no error
    }
}, 'json');
```

// PHP

```
<?php

// You don't need to json_decode the $_POST data, but you can sanitize or
// perform any validation check if you want

$id = $_POST['id'];
$id_key = $_POST['id_key'];
$table = $_POST['table'];
$data = $_POST['data'];

// Your process here

echo json_encode($rlt);
exit;
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Sorry, I miss te precise that all my variables are `JSON.stringify` before that

Comment: I try your javascript and juste put a `
echo json_encode('ok');
exit();` but nothing append...it run in the `fail()`

Comment: If you put only `echo json_encode('ok')` , it won't work because the javascript is expecting an object with the structure `{erreur: boolean, request: '...'}`. You can test with `echo json_encode(['erreur' => true]); exit; ` in your PHP.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your issue. If your php contains only `echo json_encode(['erreur' => true]); exit;` the javascript should execute the `if (data.erreur) { ... }` section. Maybe you can post your full script (js and php) so we can better understand what's going on

Comment: Yes this is working with only `echo json_encode(['erreur' => true); exit;`

Comment: So the error must come from my php side...thank you for this step in the resolution ;)

Comment: I have try my code but I just switch the echo with the `echo json_encode(['erreur' => true]); exit;`from before, and it do not work anymore. So I must have something realy bad in it...I will make some trys