# I need $http POST Status code 400, but getting 200

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have this code

```
var body="ok";
var suc=0; var failed=0;
$http({
           url: API.toUrl('api/xxxx/xxxx'),
                method: 'POST',
                data: body
            }).then(function(response) {
                if(response.status==200){
                    suc=suc+1;
                }
                if(response.status==400){
                    failed=failed+1;
                }                        
            });
```

My problem in this is that I can't obtain the 400 Status Code, I am only getting 200 but not 400. How can I get 400 status code in my `response` parameter.

I am working in Angular, any idea for obtain the 400?

Thanks

Comment: I want if the response status it's 400 sum a variable, but I cant handle with response.status

Comment: Hey @Jhonny Afonso, did you see my solution?

Answer (score 0):

`400` status code will come as an error, `then` accept two functions as parameters first one for OK response and second one for errors so you have to catch `400` on error function.

So if you want to catch it you should do it like this:

```
  var body = "ok";
  var suc = 0;
  var failed = 0;
  $http({
      url: API.toUrl('api/xxxx/xxxx'),
      method: 'POST',
      data: body
  }).then(
      function(response) {
         if (response.status == 200) {
          suc = suc + 1;
         }
      }, 
      function(error) {
          //Catch 400 here
      }
  );
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using PHP server to write your api's/services then  use below lines to manually send `400` to your `$http` request

```
<?php

// Get the current response code and set a new one
var_dump(http_response_code(400));

// Get the new response code
var_dump(http_response_code());
?>
```

**[UPDATE]**
You can see more examples here to check how to send response codes:
[PHP: How to send HTTP response code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3258634/php-how-to-send-http-response-code)

Comment: are you using a PHP server to send response back to your client code?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use another function for errors (400):

```
var body="ok";
var suc=0; var failed=0;
$http({
           url: API.toUrl('api/xxxx/xxxx'),
                method: 'POST',
                data: body
            }).then(function(response) {
                alert response.status ;
              },function error(response) {
                alert response.status ;
            });
```

Answer (score 0):

From the Docs:

> A response status code between 200 and 299 is considered a success status and will result in the success callback being called. Any response status code outside of that range is considered an error status and will result in the error callback being called.

-- [AngularJS $http Service API Reference](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http)

```
var body="ok";
var suc=0; var failed=0;
$http.post(url, data).then(function onSuccess(response) {
    if(response.status==200){
        suc=suc+1;
    };
    //return to chain response
    return response;
}).catch(function onReject(errorResponse) {
    if(errorResponse.status==400){
        failed=failed+1;
    }
    //throw to chain rejection
    throw errorResponse;                        
});
```

If chaining from the httpPromise, be sure to use a `throw` statement in the `onReject` handler to avoid **converting** the rejection to a success.