# Let 400 errors pass through Apache

Tags: php, apache, http-headers, bitnami

Via PHP, I output a 400 Bad Request header along with a message in the body of the response. Yet Apache keeps on blocking it and returns a 500 Internal Error.

I believe its an Apache issue - not a PHP one. Can someone tell me how to let those pass through?

Answer (score 0):

Hot damn! Turns out the issue was PHP after all. PHP-FPM its a little tricky. The solution was to send the header this way:

`header("X-PHP-Response-Code: $code", true, $code);`

As explained here:
[PHP: How to send HTTP response code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3258634/php-how-to-send-http-response-code)

Thanks Stackoverflow!