# Creating a function that accepts Error Codes and Messages in PHP

Tags: php

If i was to have an array of error codes I.E. `$error_code =[400=> "Bad request", 404 => "Not found"];`.

How would i create a function that accepts 2 input parameters `error_code` & `error_message`. And prints out a header that has the form: `Protocol Code - Reason(custom message dependant on what went wrong)`.

I.E. `"error": 400 - Bad Request: Name contains whitespaces`

Comment: it's unclear where you are stuck. The simple answer is `function showError($code, $message) { // do your formatting and output }`

Comment: i'm not sure what to put in the formatting.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP: How to send HTTP response code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3258634/php-how-to-send-http-response-code)

Comment: StackOverflow isn't your personal coding factory. Try to learn some PHP.

Comment: I'm not really sure thats a duplicate. I'm trying to use a function to output not just use header and if statements

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible to use header(); for something like that, but you can echo/return the function.

As far as I understand this should be the solution:

```
function getError($error_code, $error_message) {
echo "error: ".$error_code." - ".$error_message;
}
```

Please note that you will need to format the error message if you want to get the result you mentioned in your question.