# How to handle errors in Zapier?

Tags: php, mysql, zapier

I am building an integration with Zapier (https://zapier.com/platform) and I want to throw an error but it seems like it's not working properly.

My authentication code (dumbed down for the purpose of this post):

```
if($_POST['api_key'] === $row['api_key']) {
    $array = ['success' => 'yes'];
    echo json_encode($array);
} else {
    echo "Sorry but that is the invalid API token. Please try something else";
}
```

When I try to test that in the Zapier developer platform, I get this message from them:

> Error parsing response. We got: "Sorry but that is the invalid API token. Please try something else". This is likely a problem with the app. Please contact support at contact@zapier.com

But Zapier wants me to throw an error that does not have the "Error parsing response" and "This is likely a problem with the app..." parts....

How can I fix this?

Comment: It's likely expecting a specific JSON-formatted response which you are not providing.

Comment: @AlexHowansky Yes I know that but if I provide JSON response, it shows "success". Not sure if that's what it is supposed to actually show...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply sending a message that the auth was unsuccessful isn't enough - you need to also send the appropriate HTTP response code. In this case, you probably want 403 or 401. I'm not sure how to do that, but there [plenty of questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3258634/php-how-to-send-http-response-code) that'll point you in the right direction.

Additionally, you probably want to send back JSON rather than plain text. This could be as simple as: `{"message": "invalid token"}`. This'll help the client better surface that info to the user.

Comment: Hey @xavdid - I tried sending this JSON response but Zapier still doesn't pick the value under "message" key to show the same to the user. Is there anything I am missing.

Just to let you know I was also sending the proper HTTP response code as well.

Comment: Zapier won't automatically pick up the `message` key unless you are specifically looking for it. I just used that as a simple example. You'll need to handle that error manually