# How to set https error status to 404 using PHP such that it can be handled by .htaccess file?

Tags: php, .htaccess

I am using PHP for my project and I have `.htaccess` file which has code below;

```
ErrorDoccument 404 /error-handler.php
```

This code is used to send or use `error-handler.php` file for every `404` error. Everything till here is working. But I want a file named `call-404.php` which when opened from browser should show 404 error and it must be handled by `.htaccess` file above. I tried using;

```
http_response_code(404);
```

also,

```
header("HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found");
```

All the above code does says `HTTP ERROR FILE NOT FOUND` but the 404 at this condition does not does as per `.htaccess` file. It just displays browser defined 404 error page. What is the solution for it?

And This question is not simply 404 redirection using `.htaccess` or simply use of `http_response_code(404);`. This question shows and wants solution of inability of `.htaccess` redirection on response to `http_response_code(404)`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [PHP: How to send HTTP response code?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3258634/3415984)

Comment: @ttrasn No it doesnot work

Answer (score -1):

The whole point of `ErrorDoccument 404 /error-handler.php` is that if NO resource is found (be it image, php script or whatever) then apache will use that directive and head to that 404 page. If however you have reached one of your own scripts, then a resource was found and therefore that .htaccess rule will not be triggered.

But you're almost there. Just header and then call the script!

```
<?php

header("HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found");
echo file_get_contents('/path/to/your/404page.php');
```

I presume that the 404 page has nothing dynamic and is just plain HTML?

Comment: Your answer was also right but the below one was more dynamic.

Comment: this also does not work? It is not sending https status code(404) it is simply requiring. My objective is to use `.htaccess` file to do so

Comment: Can you suggest me another?